# How do I pass an actual variable to a text file in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I am creating a script that needs to generate commit messages based on timestamps for automatic backups in a private repository.

```
echo "#!/bin/bash   
     cd ${DIRECTORY}
     git add .
     git commit -m 'Backup $(date +%s)'
     git push origin master
" >> backup.sh
```

The timestamp `$(date +%s)` variable must be printed as is in the file instead of printing the timestamp when this file is generated.

How do I pass the actual variable to the text file in bash?

*I have tried back ticks and it prints nothing. Maybe I am trying it wrong?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have the option of using a *heredoc* to append to `backup.sh`. A heredoc provides the additional control of allowing tab indention preservation using `<<-` and providing control over variable expansion by single quoting the heredoc sigil (e.g. `'EOF'`)

In your case if you wanted to expand `${DIRECTORY}` but preserve `$(date +%s)` you could simply use:

```
cat << EOF >> backup.sh
#!/bin/bash   
cd ${DIRECTORY}
git add .
git commit -m 'Backup \$(date +%s)'
git push origin master
EOF
```

Which would append the contents to `backup.sh` with the proper directory and `$(date +%s)` instead of the timestamp.

If you want `${DIRECTORY}` and `$(date +%s)` to both be input into `backup.sh` -- as written -- without expansion, simply single quote the first `'EOF'`, e.g.

```
cat << 'EOF' >> backup.sh
#!/bin/bash   
cd ${DIRECTORY}
git add .
git commit -m 'Backup $(date +%s)'
git push origin master
EOF
```

If it helps you think about what is actually happening you can also write:

```
cat >> backup.sh << EOF
...
EOF
```

(if you like to think about "everything between `EOF ... EOF` going into `backup.sh`)

Comment: The single quotes around the commit message prevent the `date` command from executing at all.

Comment: @tripleee - not so, they are treated as single-quotes within double-quotes if the sigil is unquoted.

Comment: But in your second example, it is quoted. Oh well, I guess we are both second-guessing what the OP actually wants.

Comment: Yes, and neither will expand -- which is I think what the question was asking for. In the first with the unquoted sigil, the `${DIRECTORY}` was left to expand, but the command substitution around `date` was escape to prevent expansion as the question described. Being unclear on whether the question wanted only one, or both, I gave both examples.

Answer (score 3):

how about using single quotes instead of double quotes because

*Single `(')` quotes won't interpolate anything, but double `(")` quotes will*
refer some more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

```
echo '#!/bin/bash   
     cd ${DIRECTORY}
     git add .
     git commit -m "Backup $(date +%s)"
     git push origin master
' >> backup.sh
```

on a completely different note `'>>'` do you really want this to be an append operator ?

Comment: That is very handy information, thanks! That worked.

Comment: Not me for the downvote :( So >> is append right? I'll do some more research.

Comment: The string you are enclosing in single quotes contains single quotes, which need to be escaped.  You need to either escape the `$` characters in a double-quoted string, or escape the `'` characters in a single-quoted string.  Also, this answer prevents `${DIRECTORY}` from being expanded, which was not indicated as a problem in the original question.

Comment: @paddy You can't escape a single-quote inside a single-quoted string, since escapes aren't recognized there. But it looks to me like the argument to `git commit -m` should be double-quoted instead of single-quoted, so it's a moot point.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `$` indicates an expansion (in this case `$(..)` executes the `date` program), you simply need to escape the character so it's translated as a literal `$`.

To do this, prefix it with a backslash: `\$`